# Обнулить Final объект JFrame

Tags: java, swing

Необходимо вернуть объект `JFrame` в изначальное состояние, который имеет тип `final`

```
static final JFrame frame2 = new JFrame("Информация об ученике");
...
MainJava.jTabPeople.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {

            //Здесь необходимо обнулять этот JFrame

                frame2.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame2.setSize(400, 300);
                frame2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                frame2.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                frame2.setResizable(false);
                frame2.setVisible(true);
                ...
       }
)};
```

Comment: совсем не понятно что вы делаете

Comment: Есть final объект JFrame, который при вызове одного метода необходимо вернуть в исходное состояние, как будто это только созданный объект

Comment: приведите код, какое состояние, какой метод, больше конкретики

Comment: а что значит обнулять?

Comment: Вернуть в исходное состояние, как если бы я ввел  frame2 = new JFrame();

Comment: т.е. убрать содержимое?

Comment: Да, можно и так сказать

Comment: создать новый объект вместо старого вы не можете из-за модификатора final вы можете только вручную поменять все в исходное состояние

Comment: если речь идет только о содержимом есть метод frame.removeAll();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создать новый объект вместо старого вы не можете из-за модификатора final вы можете только вручную поменять все что получится в исходное состояние, например вызвать метод `removeAll()` для удаления компонентов, добавленных на фрейм. Или же вам надо убрать final и создавать новые окна.